# jqgrid 2 grid on same row, 1x left, 1x right

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

How can I make on a html page, 2 jqgrids, on same row, 1x left and 1x right?

on default came one on top, one bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a table with a single row (tr), and put the left grid in the first cell (td) and the right grid in the next cell.